# Zend2 navigation remove "href"

Tags: javascript, css, navigation, zend-framework2

Zend2 navigation from array passed in `Zend\Navigation\Navigation` works fine if child items are opened on parent item mouse hover. If they opened on mouse click undesirable actions happen. User can not go directly to child page. At first page from parent menu item is opened.

```
<nav>
    <ul class="sidebar">
    <li>
        <a class="item-1" href="parent-page1">Parent page1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="item-1" href="child-page11">Child page11</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="item-1" href="child-page12">Child page12</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a class="item-1" href="parent-page2">Parent page2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="item-1" href="child-page21">Child page21</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="item-1" href="child-page22">Child page22</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Problem could be solved if there be an option to remove "href" attribute from parent item completely. However I can't find such option in Zend2 docs or examples. I believe it's my fault because there must be some possibility to parse menus with click-able parent items. That type menus are used in popular admin panels such as [AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview).

For now I'm using solution that does not look nice. In navigation array I'm adding `'class' => 'not-active'` to each parent item. Then in application layout JavaScript does the job

```
window.onload = function () {
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("not-active");
    for(var i=0,j=x.length; i<j; i++){
      x[i].removeAttribute("href");
    };
}
```

**EDIT**

Finally found the solution. Have to add new route in `module.config.php`

```
        'empty' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array('route' => '#'),
        ),
```

Then use it in navigation array

```
         array(
            'label' => 'Parent page1', 
            'route' => 'empty',
            'controller' => 'admins',
            'resource'  => 'Admin\Controller\Admins',
            'privilege' => 'index',
            'pages' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Child page11',
                    'route' => 'admin/default',
                    'controller' => 'admins',
                    'resource'  => 'Admin\Controller\Modules',
                    'privilege' => 'index',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Child page12',
                    'route' => 'admin/default',
                    'controller' => 'modules',
                    'resource'  => 'Admin\Controller\Modules',
                    'privilege' => 'index',
                ),
             ),
         ),
```

**EDIT 2**

Unfortunately the solution does not work when site is located in subpath.

I got `<a href="#">Parent 1</a>` from `example.com`

but `<a href="subpath/#">Parent 1</a>` from `example.com/subpath/`

So I'm back to Javascript's post processing :(

Answer (score 1):

You simply could add # as parent href.

```
<a href="#">Parent 1</a>
```

On click the browser don't reload or go somewhere, you stay on that site.